# Multiple trusted kestores of the one weblogic

Tags: security, ssl, weblogic, keystore

we have the one weblogic server deployed on the particular hardware machine and there is a number on instances managed by mentioned server. All the instances are configured as a clusters, but all the nodes share the same hardware machine.

Now each particular instance uses its own trusted/identity keystore (means that all the nodes of the one instance share the same trusted/identity keystore), stored under the instance's root directory.

Please advise what is the proper way to follow? should we use the same keystores among all the instances stored under the WLS root directory?

what are the procs and cons of both ways (i'm also interested in case, when nodes use **different** hardware machines)?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the same trustedstore or keystore.It may be within the server or in any other server it may be physical or virtual